# Why configuration in custom module is not automatically removed on uninstall in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I would like to understand why if I uninstall my custom module and install it again I get an error saying that some config already exist. **Is this the expected behaviour?**

I'm removing the config manually inside hook_uninstall(). **Is this the correct way of handling this problem?**

I have tried with module dependencies as other posts say but that way there is a circular dependency and module won't be installed as requirements are not satisfied.

I know i could use optional instead of install but that way the config never gets removed.

```
=== demo_rest_api/config/install/node.type.example_mytype.yml ===

type: example_mytype
name: Example
description: 'Use <em>example</em> content to get to Drupal 8 development better.'
help: ''
new_revision: false
display_submitted: true
preview_mode: 1
status: true
langcode: en



=== demo_rest_api/demo_rest_api.install ===

function demo_rest_api_uninstall(){
    \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('node.type.example_mytype')->delete();
}
```

I would expect that the config is removed by default on module uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make sure the config behaves as expected upon uninstallation is to add this to your config file before it is installed the first time:

```
dependencies:
    - demo_rest_api
```

This way it will just delete itself when the module is uninstalled.

Another option, is to move the configuration file from `config/install` to `config/optional` and then the collision will not cause the module to fail installation.

Comment: Hello Isaiah, thanks for your response but, as I said, that way I run into circular dependency and the module cannot be installed if uninstalled

Comment: Yes, go ahead and manually remove the configuration. But in the future, if the config has an explicit dependency of the original module, then it will uninstall itself automatically. I will edit my answer for clarification.